# REACT JS : Error 300 and error 310 render error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting "Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement." and "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render." errors. I think everything is clear. How can I fix that? Here is my code:

```
 const [isSecure, setIsSecure] = useState<boolean>(true)
  const [isTabEmpty, setIsTabEmpty] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const history = useHistory()
  const curTab = useSelector(getCurrTab)
  const tabHosts = useSelector(getTabHosts)

  const hosts = curTab && curTab.id ? tabHosts[curTab.id] : []
  const url = curTab && curTab.url ? curTab.url.split('/')[2] : undefined
  const urlWithoutSplit = curTab ? curTab.url : undefined
  const host = urlWithoutSplit ? new URL(urlWithoutSplit) : undefined
  const protocol = host ? host.protocol : undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hostIsSecure() !== isSecure) {
      setIsSecure(hostIsSecure)
    } else if (tabEmpty() !== isTabEmpty) {
      setIsTabEmpty(tabEmpty)
    }
  }, [host])

  function hostIsSecure(): boolean {
    if (protocol && protocol === 'https:') {
      return true
    } else return false
  }

  function tabEmpty(): boolean {
    const curTabId = curTab ? curTab.id : undefined
    if (curTabId && tabHosts[curTabId] && tabHosts[curTabId].length === 0)
      return true
    else return false
  }
```

Comment: what are your returning? is this a hook or a function component?

Comment: @punjira I am returning a list